# Using while -or operator cause infinite loop

Tags: powershell

Hello I am trying to add -or operator to my Script to avoid and infinite script run using a counter but I don´t get that works, if I don´t use -or over while It´s work ok but if I add the program script, run infinite

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$server = "server1"
$evtsrc = "AppPool Resurrector"
$loopcounter = 0

if ( [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($evtsrc) -eq $false){
New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $evtsrc
}

while((Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | where {$_.state -eq "Stopped"}).count -gt 0 -or ($loopcounter -lt 20))
{   
  $appPools = Get-ChildItem -Path 'IIS:\AppPools' | where {$_.state -eq "Stopped"} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
  foreach ($appPoolName in $appPools) {
    Start-WebAppPool $appPoolName
    Write-Host ($appPoolName)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    $loopcounter++
    if ((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $appPoolName).Value -eq "Started"){
     Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Message "Start Application Pool `"$appPoolName`" because SMB Client is connected again." -Source $evtsrc -EntryType Warning -EventId 666 -Category 0
    }
else{
    write-Host ("test")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use `-and` instead if you want it to stop after `$loopcounter` reaches 20 :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen so if I use -and I need that first and second if statment are true not? I want that though the first statment is grather than 0 If the count is grather than 20 for example the script stop

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-and` instead of `-or` here, like [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)  already commented.

Also, I would suggest using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) the arguments for the `Write-EventLog` cmdlet to make the code more readable and easier to maintain.

Something like below:

```
$loopcounter = 0
$appPools = Get-ChildItem -Path 'IIS:\AppPools' | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Stopped"}
# as long as there are stopped app pools AND we have not yet reached the max for the loop counter
while ($appPools.Count -gt 0 -and ($loopcounter -lt 20)) {   
    $appPools | Foreach-Object {
        $appPoolName = $_.Name
        Write-Host "Starting '$appPoolName'"
        Start-WebAppPool $appPoolName
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10   # that's a mighty long wait..
        $loopcounter++
        if ((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $appPoolName).Value -eq 'Started') {
            $splat = @{
                'LogName'   = 'Application'
                'Message'   = "Start Application Pool '$appPoolName' because SMB Client is connected again."
                'Source'    = $evtsrc
                'EntryType' = 'Warning'
                'EventId'   = 666
                'Category'  = 0
            }
            Write-EventLog @splat
        }
        else{
            write-Host ("test: Counter = $loopcounter")
        }
    }
    # refresh the app pools variable
    $appPools = Get-ChildItem -Path 'IIS:\AppPools' | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Stopped"}
}
```

Hope that helps